# Expected an indented block - Python

Tags: python

I tried to make a simple alarm .But when I run the code it shows an IndentationError.The code is here.please give me an answer.

```
import time
import winsound
print("Made by Ethan")


def myAlarm():
    try:
    myTime = list(map(int, input("Enter time in hr min sec\n") .split()))
    if len(mytime) == 3:
        total_secounds = myTime[0]*60*60+myTime[1]*60+myTime[2]
        time.sleep(total_secounds)
        frequency = 2500  
        duration = 10  
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
    else:
        print("Please enter time in correct format as mentioned\n")
        myAlarm()
    exept Exception as e:
    print("This is the exception\n ", e, "So!, please enter correct details")
    myAlarm()


myAlarm()
```

Comment: try blocks and except blocks need indents as well.

Comment: Why do you think you're getting an indentation error? What have you already tried to fix the problem yourself? Are you aware that indentation is important in Python? BTW you misspelled `except`. And BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were three mistakes in your code

1. Indentation of try-except block
2. Spelling of except
3. at one place you have used myTime and at another mytime.

```
import time
import winsound
print("Made by Ethan")


def myAlarm():
    try:
        myTime = list(map(int, input("Enter time in hr min sec\n") .split()))
        if len(myTime) == 3:
            total_secounds = myTime[0]*60*60+myTime[1]*60+myTime[2]
            time.sleep(total_secounds)
            frequency = 2500
            duration = 10
            winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        else:
            print("Please enter time in correct format as mentioned\n")
            myAlarm()
    except Exception as e:
        print("This is the exception\n ", e,
              "So!, please enter correct details")
        myAlarm()


myAlarm()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try/except blocks also need to be indented in Python:

```py
def myAlarm():
    try:
        myTime = list(map(int, input("Enter time in hr min sec\n") .split()))
        if len(mytime) == 3:
            total_secounds = myTime[0]*60*60+myTime[1]*60+myTime[2]
            time.sleep(total_secounds)
            frequency = 2500  
            duration = 10  
            winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        else:
            print("Please enter time in correct format as mentioned\n")
            myAlarm()
    except Exception as e:
        print("This is the exception\n ", e, "So!, please enter correct details")

myAlarm()
```

Answer (score 1):

As flakes mentioned, your `try` block and `except` block need to be indented.
Another error is that `except` is misspelled as `exept`.

```
import time
import winsound
print("Made by Ethan")


def myAlarm():
    try:
      myTime = list(map(int, input("Enter time in hr min sec\n") .split()))
      if len(mytime) == 3:
          total_secounds = myTime[0]*60*60+myTime[1]*60+myTime[2]
          time.sleep(total_secounds)
          frequency = 2500  
          duration = 10  
          winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
      else:
          print("Please enter time in correct format as mentioned\n")
          myAlarm()
    except Exception as e:
      print("This is the exception\n ", e, "So!, please enter correct details")
      myAlarm()


myAlarm()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try-except` indention creates the problem:

```
def myAlarm():
    try:
        myTime = list(map(int, input("Enter time in hr min sec\n") .split()))
        if len(mytime) == 3:
            total_secounds = myTime[0]*60*60+myTime[1]*60+myTime[2]
            time.sleep(total_secounds)
            frequency = 2500  
            duration = 10  
            winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        else:
             print("Please enter time in correct format as mentioned\n")
             myAlarm()
    except Exception as e: # <--- spelling corrected from exept to except
        print("This is the exception\n ", e, "So!, please enter correct details")
        myAlarm()
```